# How do I execute a list of commands in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I have been using `system` to execute shell commands for me, since I'm only interested in exit status. I noticed that since I can do something like:

```
ls <- system "ls"
pwd <- system "pwd"
```

and this correctly executes the two commands. I was thinking about executing an array of these commands eg

```
lsAndPwd <- return $ system <$> ["ls", "pwd"]
```

and I'm surprised that this doesn't actually execute anything. This compiles and I checked that `lsAndPwd` has the correct type of `[IO GHC.IO.Exception.ExitCode]` but the commands are never executed. What's going on and how can I get this to work?

Comment: Roughly, `return x` means "don't do any IO, just return value `x`", so that can never execute anything. Also, the type `[IO GHC.IO.Exception.ExitCode]` is (roughly) the type of a list of actions that, when they will be run, they will produce an `ExitCode` each. So, you built a list of actions without actually running them. If you had run them, you'd have a result of type `[GHC.IO.Exception.ExitCode]` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `mapM` instead of `<$>` so you get an `IO [ExitCode]`, not an `[IO ExitCode]`. This way, it's collected into one IO monad that you can run:

```hs
lsAndPwd <- mapM system ["ls", "pwd"]
```

Alternatively, call `sequence` on the whole thing:

```hs
lsAndPwd <- sequence $ system <$> ["ls", "pwd"]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but I'm still confused on why my approach doesn't. My logic is that `return $ system <$> ["ls", "pwd"]` will go through each element in the array and apply `system` such that we will get an `IO [system "ls", system "pwd"]`. Why wouldn't this execute each command?

Comment: You have an array of IO monads, that you then wrapped in an IO monad that doesn't do anything (via `return`). When you then run that whole monad, you just run the useless IO monad from `return`, and you get back the array of IO monads, and none of the IO monads have been run.

Comment: @Kiwibreeder `IO` actions are "inert" unless they lie in the way of the `main :: IO ()` do-block or one that is reached from it using do-notation or monadic binds (`>>=`). In particular, they can be stored in containers like any other value. So, if you have a list of `IO` actions, you need some kind of combinator that turns the list of `IO` actions into an `IO` action that returns a list. That resulting action could be put into `main`'s do-block and get executed. There is a family of functions that do things like this, like `sequence`, `traverse`, `traverse_`, `for` and `for_`.

Comment: Thank you both, this really helped me understand io actions better